# LyX: Fix bookmark to specific text (rather than line number)

Tags: lyx, bookmarks

I initially place a bookmark (Shift+F1) at the start of this line:

[image]

Now when I hit "Ctrl+1", LyX moves me to the position just before the word "Bookmark", as desired. Great.

[image]

After adding the sentence starting with "But now", the bookmark now moves to the start of that line. That is, when I hit "Ctrl+1", LyX moves me to the position just before the word
"But".

How do I get LyX to keep the bookmark at just before the word "Bookmark"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short answer: this is fixed and will be included in LyX 2.4.0, which we're in the (long) process of releasing. You can see the code for the specific fix [here](https://www.lyx.org/trac/changeset/86bfa10a/lyxgit).

Below I'll add more information on bookmarks, and the specific feature you like.

The bookmarks are currently stored in the "session" file inside your user directory (see Help > About for the location of this directory).

If you take a look in the session file you will see something like this:

```
[bookmarks]
0, 91, 45, /home/scott/montetools-rpaper/presentation/monte.lyx
1, 100, 3, /home/scott/montetools-rpaper/presentation/monte.lyx
2, 98, 8, /home/scott/montetools-rpaper/presentation/monte.lyx
```

The first number of the row refers to the bookmark number (might be off by 1); the second number refers to the paragraph number; and the third number refers to the character in that line number. So there is no information stored that LyX could use to anchor the bookmark to a word or something like that. The way that LyX tries to "preserve" the bookmarks is that if you edit the paragraph, it adjusts the column position of a bookmark. For example, if you add text before a bookmark, it knows to add that number of characters to the stored bookmark.

You might be interested in following [this issue](https://www.lyx.org/trac/ticket/12565), which is related.

EDIT: if you want to test a beta version of LyX 2.4.0, you can do so here: http://ftp.lyx.org/pub/lyx/devel/lyx-2.4/.  It's reasonably stable, but I would only use it for testing since any file you save can't be opened in 2.3.x. We'd be very curious for your feedback if you end up testing.

Comment: Thanks for your great work! Around when can we expect LyX 2.4.0 to be released?

Comment: Thanks :). I haven't been doing much work recently on LyX, but thankfully some have been pushing us towards the release. We haven't discussed dates, but my guess would be somewhere around January. You can see the long list of things to look forward to when it's released here: https://wiki.lyx.org/LyX/NewInLyX24